# Correct way to select multiple list elements by name

Tags: r, list

What is the correct way to return a new list with some but not all list elements referred to by name?  For example:

```
$`listA`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$listB
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$listC
[1] 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

should become:

```
$`listA`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$listC
[1] 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Here's some data:

```
list1 <- 1:10
list2 <- letters[1:26]
list3 <- 25:32
mylist <- list(list1,list2,list3)
names(mylist) <- c("listA", "listB", "listC")
```

Comment: `mylist[c("listA", "listC")]`

Comment: And if you want to remove some of them do: `mylist[c("listA","listB")] = NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `[` operator like:

```
mylist[c("listA", "listC")]
```

**Output:**

```
$`listA`
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$listC
[1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

Note that when selecting one element from a list using `[`, the output might not be what we expect:

```
mylist["listA"]
```

**Output:**

```
$`listA`
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> class(mylist["listA"])
[1] "list"
```

Here we see that selecting the element `"listA"` using `[` *does not* return the element itself, but instead, returns a list that *contains* the `"listA"` element. If we want to subset the element itself by name, we should use the `[[` operator:

```
mylist[["listA"]]
```

**Output:**

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> class(mylist[["listA"]])
[1] "integer"
```

Another difference between `[` and `[[` is that `[[` can only be used to select a single element. For example, the following would not work:

```
mylist[[c("listA", "listC")]]
```

> Error in mylist[[c("listA", "listC")]] : subscript out of bounds